# why does flutter throw a string int error with buildSuggestions but buildResults still works?

Tags: flutter

Using the syntax below, I receive the string is not a subtype of int error message and the red screen. However, when I enter text in the search field, it displays the data 'season: sport' in the format that I want - what gives?
Also, I'm not sure why this syntax doesn't work in the buildS widget but works in the buildResults widget just fine.

PROBLEM
The suggestions query returns all the data in my list when I only want to present one or two fields/parameters from my List. Then when the user clicks on the selection the full list is displayed - in the ListTile that I created in buildResults.

user query search -> season or sport; suggestionList displays -> season: sport; results -> season: sport: color; id, etc is displayed.

```
Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    final List<dynamic> suggestionList;
    if (query.isEmpty) {
      suggestion = search;
    } else {
      suggestionList = controls
          .where((index) =>
              index[’season’].toLowerCase().contains(query) 
          .toList();
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          close(context, 'a');
        },
        title: Text(suggestionList[index][‘season’]
                .toString())),
       subtitle: Text(suggestionList[index][‘sport’]
                .toString())),    
      itemCount: suggestion.length,
    );
  }




Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final List<dynamic> suggestionList;

    if (query.isEmpty) {
      suggestionList = recentSearch;
    } else {
      suggestionList = controls
          .where((index) =>
              index[‘season’].toLowerCase().contains(query) )
          .toList();
    }

    return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              showResults(context);
            },
            title: Text(suggestionList[index][‘season’]
                .toString())), ,
        itemCount: suggestion.length);
  }
```

Comment: Please always include the error message in your questions. It is easier to start from there.

Comment: Somewhere you try to use an integer while you are having a String. Error message should show in which line.

Comment: ERROR MSG: 
The following _TypeError was thrown building: type String is not a subtype of type int of index.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: DataSearch.buildSuggestions<anonymous closure>(package:app/main.dart:8410:46)

CODE
title:   title: Text(suggestionList[index][‘season’])),

Comment: I am trying to retrieve and display the items in the list/array for season - winter, spring, etc..

final colors = [
              {'id': 01, 'season': 'winter', 'sports': 'ski', 'color': 'blue'},
              {'id': 02,'season': 'spring', 'sports': 'cycling', 'color': 'green}
                ];

title:   title: Text(suggestionList[index]).toString())
works but it returns all the items in the list - as a string - which essentially reveals my entire data/list structure

Comment: `Text(suggestionList[index][‘season’]))` <-- I bet that returns with an integer, but the Text() expects a String. Do this: `Text('${suggestionList[index][‘season’])}')`

Comment: @stacktrace2234 - thanks but that didn't work. same error message. I'm currently researching the <anonymous closure> reference in the error message.